# See through a background of a Table to the background of site

Tags: css, image, scroll, transparent, css-tables

This is hard to explain, but I will try. I have a background image in CSS, and then I have a table over the top of it, which has a white background. So you can't see the background in CSS.

But the effect I want is to be able to hover over a circular image or shape which then reveals the background in that small area.

A way to visualise this, I have a photo on the table, I put a piece of paper over the image so none of the image is in view. I now cut a hole in the paper so I can then see the photo through that hole. Plus as I move the paper around the image behind changes as I looking at a different part.

This is used here http://www.thebestdesigns.com/2012/05/18/andy-chak/ with the letters going through to the background.

Any ideas would be great, but I under stand if this is not possible.

Comment: Can you share your code in jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting a background colour on the whole table you could put the background colour on the individual table cells.

```
td, th { background:#fff; }
```

Then when you hover over a table cell:

```
td:hover, th:hover { background:none; }
```

Or if you wanted to show larger areas you could add a class onto a cluster of cells then do the same as above to turn off the background on that cluster of cells which all have a specific class:

```
td.my-class-name:hover, th.my-class-name:hover { background:none; }
```

Obviously this is not circular shapes but a possible solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can set one of the table cells' background color to `transparent` when hovering. Although, to get this work you should have your white background set on `td`, not to `table`, like the following:

```
td {
    background-color:white;
}

td:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/a2jp5/1/